# What are the issues with protected class-member access?

Tags: java, oop, language-design

Java has a protected mode for the members of its classes that allow sub-classes access to them. I read somewhere that there are issues with this. The only issue I can think of is that a programmer might forget the protected members are part of the API and cannot be change arbitrarily. Are there other issues?

Answer (score 0):

Of the four member access levels, private and default (package-private) are concordant with encapsulation, i.e. members that are hidden preserve the autonomy of your implementation details.  In other words, the less that the users of your API know about your class implementation details, the less you are tied to that implementation and the freer you are to change it at any time without breaking the contracts your API users have relied upon.

As soon as you go up to protected access (and public access) then you are bound to that implementation and must continue to support it until your API's life ends (or you go out of business).  Accessible members tend to tie you to a particular implementation, even if you'd like to change it, so ... lots of accessible members are not concordant with tight encapsulation.

But more than that, access also exports risk.  The more aspects of your class that are exported by your API, then there are more potential exploits that malicious users can try and hack.

Protected access, for example, can be used to override methods in your class that you had forgotten to make final.  This can break your API and, worse, enable malicious users to access instance data that you did not intend to allow.

Comment: Users do not see the code, only programmers. And what's to stop a programmer from adding malicious intent anywhere in the code?

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm not seeing that a protected member of any class could be considered part of a public API, given that a `protected` field or function [is not visible to the world](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

Ultimately, when writing an API, the idea is to have the interface, or contract, be as unchanging as possible; *how* it's done can change with each revision (although hopefully, not too much).

One issue I could potentially see with protected members in classes would be overriding their behavior to produce radically divergent behavior from the parent, while satisfying the *generic* contract of the API (that is, if I'm expecting a numerical value, I get it back; if I'm expecting a boolean, I get it back.  The *correctness* of the value/boolean is suspect, though, and should be tested).

**Example:**  Suppose I have a class `Parent` and a class `Child`.  Both implement an interface called `Teachable`.  This allows them to learn a particular `Subject`, which is a simple enumeration construct.  The contract for `Teachable` is given as:

```
public interface Teachable {
/**
 * Learn a particular subject.
 * This requires that the element being learned hasn't previously been learned.
 * @param thisSubject the subject to be learned
 * @return whether or not the subject learned was unique.
 */
    public boolean hasLearned(Subject thisSubject);
}
```

Suppose now we have our implementation of the `Parent` and `Child` classes as follows:

```
public class Parent implements Teachable {

    private Set<Subject> subjectsLearned = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    public boolean hasLearned(final Subject thisSubject) {
        return learn(thisSubject);
    }

    protected boolean learn(final Subject theSubject) {
        return subjectsLearned.add(theSubject);
    }

}

class Child extends Parent {

    private Set<Subject> subjectsLearned = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    public boolean hasLearned(final Subject thisSubject) {
        return learn(thisSubject);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean learn(final Subject theSubject) {
        return !subjectsLearned.add(theSubject);
    }
}
```

I've effectively changed the behavior of the class which is said to adhere to the behavior of my API, because I could override it.  The first time a `Child` learns a particular `Subject`, they'll claim they already know it.  Only the second and subsequent times would they not.

Comment: According to Joshua Bloch, encapsulation is a desirable and precious thing.  He also makes compelling arguments that inheritance breaks encapsulation and further, that inheritance should be reserved only for those class designs with an established "is a" relationship.  I am referring to your example in the most concrete sense only: since "a child is a parent" is not true, using protected methods and inheritance in this situation may lead to a brittle design.

Comment: I don't disagree.  In fact, this is likely an anti-pattern; one should really reserve inheritance for this sort of "is a" relationships, to your point.  However, it could easily be the case that an API somewhere does have a protected method which can be overridden, thus leading to an inconsistent/invalid contract.

Comment: To start with, a protected member is not part of the public API; it's part of the protected API. Next, encapsulation may be desirable but many API are just thrown together in the hopes that they work. To create a good API, you must ask two questions of each element: Is this sufficient and is this necessary? The first question ensures that the API transfers enough information to do useful work and second ensures that the API is the minimal necessary.

Comment: A member that is protected can be exported from the package.  Even if it's an outcome that is not desired or intended, that is the reason to have protected members.  Any time you have a member of your API that is exported, it must be considered part of the public API.  To not plan for this is to invite problems, particularly if you must deal with an unplanned security vulnerability after your project has been widely deployed.